# How to find every number that a certain digit is present in, and label based on them

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

the dataset I have has the id feature and the number of purchases, I want to add a new column as a label of 4 or 3 numbers contained in id

for example

```
id          total
08773338    100
08333777    80
```

for example

```
0877 = California
083 = Tokyo
```

then

```
id        total    label
08773338   100   california
08333777   80    tokyo
```

Comment: Provide input example data and expected output please. As a new user also consider reading this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is create dictionary for matching starts of numbers and labels and then set new column by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if match values by [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
d = {'0877':'California', '083':'Tokyo'}

for k, v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['id'].str.startswith(k), 'label'] = v
print (df)
         id total       label
0  08773338   100  California
1  08333777    80       Tokyo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize this with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df
         id  total       label
0  08773338    100  California
1  08333777     80       Tokyo

df.dtypes

id       string
total     int64
label    object
dtype: object

d = {'0877': 'California', '083': 'Tokyo'}
```

```
p = r'(^{})'.format('|'.join(d.keys()))

df['label'] = df['id'].str.extract(p, expand=False).map(d)
df

         id total       label
0  08773338   100  California
1  08333777    80       Tokyo
```